# Is cubic graph decomposition into claws NP-complete?

Tags: computer-science, np-complete

I am aware that deciding the existence of decomposition of a cubic graph into edge-disjoint claws is polynomial time solvable.

> What is the complexity of deciding the existence of decomposition of a cubic graph into vertex-disjoint claws? Is it NP-complete?

In the former problem, we partition the edge set into edge-disjoint claws while in the later one we partition the vertex set into vertex-disjoint claws.

This was posted on [CS StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44770/complexity-of-cubic-graph-decomposition) without answers.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem is eqivalent to the [1-perfect code problem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X94900264) in cubic graphs. Therefore, Deciding the existence of decomposition of a cubic graph into vertex disjoint claws is NP-complete.